# Rectangular signal

Tags: signal, signal-theory, formula-derivation, graph

[image]

Can someone explain me how do I take the first derivative of the given function and how will this function look like ?

Answer (score 1):

---

Very simple question, if you would've put some actual effort into it.

So your actual question is, what is the derivative of the red trace in this graph:

[image]

I'll assume you know that 1+1 = 2, but not that the derivative of sin is cos. So I'll tell  you that right now, the derivative of sin is cos.

\$x = ]0,1[\$ means that \$x\$ is between 0 and 1, but not equal to 0 or equal to 1.

\$x = [0,1[\$ means that \$x\$ can be between 0 and 1, and equal to 0 but not equal to 1.

\$x = [0,1]\$ means that \$x\$ can be between 0 and 1 and equal to 0 or 1.

---

So let's start with \$x'(t)\$ when \$t = ]0,\frac{T}{2}[\$

It appears to me that \$x(t)=V(\sin(2\pi Tt)+\frac{1}{2})\$, by looking at the graph. Though I'm not 100% sure because the \$t\$ axis is missing some indices.

Anyways, if we just derive that function we get \$x'(t)=V2\pi T\cos(2\pi Tt)\$

---

Now let's calculate \$x'(t)\$ when \$t = ]\frac{T}{2},\infty]\$

As you can see in the graph it's just 0

---

If we are clever we can see that the function is **even**, even means that \$x(t) = x(-t)\$, it's mirrored sideways. This means that we don't need to do any more work if we just do some clever absolute marking.

The final answer is this:

\$
x'(t) =
\begin{cases}
V2\pi T\cos(2\pi Tt),  & \text{if 0 < $t$<T/2} \\
V2\pi T\cos(2\pi T(t+T/2)),  & \text{if -T/2 < $t$< 0} \\
0, & \text{if |$t$|>T/2} \\
undefined, & \text{if |$t$|=T/2} \\
undefined, & \text{if $t$=0}
\end{cases}
\$

The reason for why it's undefined is because it's a discontinuity at \$t=T/2\$, and because at \$t=0\$, the derivative of \$x'(0^+)\$ is not the same as \$x'(0^-)\$, in other words, the derivative when you come from the right is not the same as the derivative when you come from the left.

This is graphically how it would look like. Just imagine that 1 = T/2, -1 = -T/2.

[image]

Taken from [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos(x*pi%20mod%20pi)%20from%20-1%20to%201).